# Unable to fit data into the GridView cell with in fixed width

Tags: asp.net, css, sql, gridview

I have a column which has has very long text i have to scroll to the end to see it. Can you help out with fitting the content in a fixed width cell

UI:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChanging_Click" 
                style="height: 166px; width: 217px; z-index: 1; left: 16px; top: 252px; position: absolute" 
                EmptyDataText="No Records Within this time Frame"  >
                <PagerSettings LastPageText="Last"  />
            </asp:GridView>

//Code Behind:   


    private void GetData()
            {
                string fromdata =  txt_fromdate.Text;//" '2013-09-23 11:06:00.077'";
                string todate =  txt_todata.Text;//" '2013-09-23 11:28:25.163' ";
                string querstring = "select * from gt_transaction_log where LogTimeStamp between" +"'"+ fromdata +"'"+ " and " +"'"+ todate + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querstring, conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
                if (TextBox1.Text != "" && int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) != 0)
                {
                    GridView1.PageSize = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
                }
                else
                { GridView1.PageSize = 10; }
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView doesn't have a Style property, but it does have a CssClass property you can use to control its CSS.

Create your CSS in a style block:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .gridViewStyle {
            height: 166px;
                width: 217px; 
                z-index: 1; 
                left: 16px; 
                top: 252px; 
                position: absolute
        }
</style>
```

Then in your GridView, it'll look like this:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="gridViewStyle" <!-- additional GV fields here -->>
</asp:Gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS:

```
.Grid{
height: 166px; width: 217px; z-index: 1; left: 16px; top: 252px; position: absolute
}
.Grid tr td{
   Width:100px;
}

  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChanging_Click" EmptyDataText="No Records Within this time Frame"></asp:GridView>
```

OR

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChanging_Click" 
                style="height: 166px; width: 217px; z-index: 1; left: 16px; top: 252px; position: absolute" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                EmptyDataText="No Records Within this time Frame"  >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your column Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Eval("EmployeeName") %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />


                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        Template fields for all columns of your datatable
                    </Columns>       
                <PagerSettings LastPageText="Last"  />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks For the solution. that code is working fine but i have a problem with the browser. I am able to run it fine in google chrome but Internet explorer is not displaying the grid properly. if the grid is larger it is extending horizontally where as i want to extend it vertically

Comment: give fix width to all the fields in the Gridview, it should not expand horizentally then.

Comment: I have edited the Css in my code. Check this if it solve your problem.